# Pine script pyramiding entry

Tags: pine-script

How can I code the pine script strategy for the entry in the next position be bellow/above a certain price diference?
Example: the last buy entry was at $100 and I want the next entry to be bellow $95 and not as soon the strategy gives another buy signal.

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.opentrades` tells you the number of open trades. You can use that to figure out if you have an open position, and if yes, check for your additional condition ($95) to execute an entry order again.

Below code is a simple example for you. For each new order the entry price will step down.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding = 3)

first_buy = 120
next_buy_step = 5

if (ta.crossover(close, first_buy))
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (strategy.opentrades > 0)
    if (ta.crossover(close, first_buy - (next_buy_step * strategy.opentrades)))
        strategy.entry("Additional Long", strategy.long)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! And it's possible to look up the last entry instead of giving it an absolute value?

Comment: Sure, create a `float var`. Update its value when you execute an entry. That way you have your latest entry price stored in a variable.

Comment: So, I can apply it in this strategy: 

if ( enterOnBorderTouchFromInside and crossunder(price, bottom) )
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, qty=tradeSize, comment="BUY")
else
    if( crossover(price, bottom) )
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, qty=tradeSize, comment="BUY")

if( crossover(price,EMA) and closeOnEMATouch )
    strategy.close("BUY")

Answer (score 0):

This is the strategy for buy:

```
if ( enterOnBorderTouchFromInside and crossunder(price, bottom) )
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, qty=tradeSize, comment="BUY")
else
    if( crossover(price, bottom) )
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, qty=tradeSize, comment="BUY")
        

if( crossover(price,EMA) and closeOnEMATouch )
    strategy.close("BUY")
```

How can I add here the code to look up the last entry price and only enter in a new pyramid trade when the price is for example 99% of the last entry price?